# Creating database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create a new database. Before this I am using `[master]`. When importing files into new database, I got an error

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'new' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'

I already clear my disk space

Answer (score 0):

Check the data file settings of your database.

If "Max Size" was determined, the error will be raised regardless the desk space.

Go to  SQL Server Management Studio: right click the database -> Properties -> Files -> Column Autogrowth/Max Size.

---

it is Supposed this answer switched to be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation , sorry.